# Is there a way to download Google Play Services SDK R15?

Tags: android, google-cast, chromecast

Is the Google Play Services SDK R15 available to download anywhere? The "ChromeCast SDK" was "released" Monday, according to hundreds of news sites. Those same news sites claim Android app developers are "hard at work implementing ChromeCast functionality." Is the SDK appearing in anyone's SDK Manager?

How are Android app developers implementing ChromeCast functionality when the SDK isn't available and the API has changed dramatically? The DayFrame developers supposedly already updated their app to the new API, which seems suspicious to me...

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** - As per the [announcement post](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/E6hpQxaoL18), SDK15 is now available.

As per the [Chromecast Android API reference](https://developers.google.com/cast/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/package-summary):

> **These APIs are currently not available for development.** They require Google Play services 4.2, which began rolling out to devices worldwide on February 3rd. Once the update to devices is complete, the corresponding Google Play services library (revision 15) will be available for you to begin using these APIs.

Certain developers have been given early access to the SDK directly from Google to allow early development, but general availability of SDK R15 is still to come. You can still read through the [Developers Guide](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/developers) and the [Android Sender App Development Guide](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender) and prepare your application, design, and resources appropriately, but the actually integration of the SDK and testing cannot occur until Google releases it officially after the full rollout of Google Play Services 4.2.

Comment: Certain developers have been given early access to a public API? I have the publicly available APK installed on my devices, but no JAR file to code against. So much for the open spirit of Android. I guess they moved it into Play Services to lock out Amazon too. What a botched rollout.

Comment: Those developers have received the actual SDK (jar and resources) required to do the development.

Comment: It's been a week and I still don't see it in my SDK manager.  Is it still rolling out?

Comment: As per the [announcement post](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/E6hpQxaoL18) SDK15 is now available.